# Show Layout from behind another layout with animation

Tags: android

I have a clickable TextView:

```
width = match_parent, height = "wrap_content"
```

When I press it, I want to show a LinearLayout containing 3 views, orientation vertical, and I want to animate it to slide down from behind the TextView, below it. Like a drop-down, but not using Spinner.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just declaring your wishes won't work out. Show what have you tried so far and where you are stuck at.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a dropdown-like effect, you should probably use a [`PopupWindow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) to show your LinearLayout. That's what `Spinner` uses internally. You can set the enter and exit animations for it. By default, a PopupWindow from a Spinner performs a scale and alpha animation at the same time.

There is also [`PopupMenu`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) which is a specialized class to show menus with the standard animations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will investigate in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Create an animation `XML` for `slide down` in `/res/anim/` folder:

**slide_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="25%" />
</set>
```

**FYI**, You can change animation `duration` and `YDelta` as per your needs.

**2.** Design your desired layout. Use `RelativeLayout` as root and set child  `LinearLayout` visibility `GONE`.

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_dropdown"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <!-- Your 3 Views here -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Click Here"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**3.** In your `Activity`, programmatically apply `slide_down` animation on `LinearLayout`(`layout_dropdown`) to show and sliding down when clicked on `TextView`(`textView`):

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_dropdown);

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Animation slideDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down);

                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                linearLayout.startAnimation(slideDown);

                // Required to keep layout stay at final position after animation
                slideDown.setFillAfter(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

Make LinearLayout with `scaleY=0`  and then animate it to 1.0

Execute this in the `onClicklistener`:

```
ViewCompat.animate(yourView)
                .scaleY(1.0f)
                .start();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question somehow.

Comment: I want the animation to slide down from behind the TextView. This is not working for me, but thanks.